# Find and replace and move a line that contains a specific string

Tags: awk, sed, grep

Assuming I have the following text file:

```
a b c d 1 2 3
e f g h 1 2 3
i j k l 1 2 3
m n o p 1 2 3
```

How do I replace '1 2 3' with '4 5 6' in the line that contains the letter (e) **and** move it after the line that contains the letter (k)?

N.B. the line that contains the letter (k) may come in *any location* in the file, the lines are not assumed to be in any order

My approach is

1. Remove the line I want to replace
2. Find the lines **before** the line I want to move it after
3. Find the lines **after** the line I want to move it after
4. append the output to a file

```
grep -v 'e' $original > $file
grep -B999 'k' $file > $output
grep 'e' $original | sed 's/1 2 3/4 5 6/' >> $output
grep -A999 'k' $file | tail -n+2 >> $output
rm $file
mv $output $original
```

but there is a lot of issues in this solution:

1. a lot of `grep` commands that seems unnecessary
2. the argument `-A999` and `-B999` are assuming the file would not contain lines more than 999, it would be better to have another way to get lines before and after the matched line

I am looking for a more efficient way to achieve that

Comment: Is this a one time replacement or global? ie, Every line with `e` moved to after every line with `k`? Or just a single replacement and then quit? If every line, what order? What if the `k` line is not found?

Comment: @dawg it should be a single replacement, and k is assumed to exist

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed '/e/{s/1 2 3/4 5 6/;h;d};/k/{G}' input_file
a b c d 1 2 3
i j k l 1 2 3
e f g h 4 5 6
m n o p 1 2 3
```

Comment: GNU sed only that...

Comment: @dawg this does not work if (k) is in a line before (e)

Comment: @Alsaraha: *this does not work if (k) is in a line before (e)* You did not state that as a requirement, but it is an easy fix with two passes.

Comment: @dawg I have not specified that it is after, can you illustrate how to do 2 passes?

Comment: @Alsaraha: Look at the edited answer...

Comment: The condition that k can be either before or after e is pretty important and, in my view should be in the question.

Comment: @DavePritlove Why do you assume that (e) is before (k). It can either be before or after (I haven't stated its position)

Comment: @Alsaraha Your sample input shows the line with 'e' before 'k' without stating otherwise. Please fix your question/sample with realistic values e.g that `k` comes before `e` so assumptions may stop being made.

Comment: @HatLess mentioned it

Comment: The only position information in your question has e before k, and no mention that the line order might be different. You really ought to explicitly state that. Im sure I'm not the only one who made a solution based on your question information only to read your comment to this answer: "*this does not work if (k) is in a line before (e)*". Help people help you and put it in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a GNU awk solution:

```
awk '
/\<e\>/{
    s=$0
    sub("1 2 3", "4 5 6", s)
    next
}
/\<k\>/ && s {
    printf("%s\n%s\n",$0,s)
    next
} 1
' file
```

Or POSIX awk:

```
awk '
function has(x) {
    for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i==x) return 1
    return 0
}

has("e") {
    s=$0
    sub("1 2 3", "4 5 6", s)
    next
}
has("k") && s {
    printf("%s\n%s\n",$0,s)
    next
} 1
' file
```

Either prints:

```
a b c d 1 2 3
i j k l 1 2 3
e f g h 4 5 6
m n o p 1 2 3
```

---

This works regardless of the order of `e` and `k` in the file:

```
awk '
function has(x) {
    for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i==x) return 1
    return 0
}

has("e") {
    s=$0
    sub("1 2 3", "4 5 6", s)
    next
}

FNR<NR && has("k") && s {
    printf("%s\n%s\n",$0,s)
    s=""
    next
}

FNR<NR

' file file
```

Answer (score 0):

This `awk` should work for you:

```bash
awk '
/(^| )e( |$)/ {
   sub(/1 2 3/, "4 5 6")
   p = $0
   next
}
1
/(^| )k( |$)/ {
   print p
   p = ""
}' file

a b c d 1 2 3
i j k l 1 2 3
e f g h 4 5 6
m n o p 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/e/{s/1 2 3/4 5 6/;s#.*#/e/d;/k/s/.*/\&\\n&/#p};' file | sed -f - file
```

Design a sed script by passing the file twice and applying the sed instructions from the first pass to the second.

---

Another solution is to use ed:

```
cat <<\! | ed file
/e/s/1 2 3/4 5 6/
/e/m/k/
wq
!
```

Or if you prefer:

```
<<<$'/e/s/1 2 3/4 5 6/\n.m/k/\nwq' ed -s file
```